# Do adjectives or adverbs describe "tio"?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, correlatives

I just completed an excercise by lernu.net. It was about when to use -e and when to use -a. The descprition told me to put an adjective when there was a noun in the phrase, and an adverb when there was none. When I came to this phrase, I disobeyed that pattern:

> Tio estas ver_.

I put in *Tio estas vere*, simply because that sounded more familiar. Now I want to know, is that grammatically wrong? I received no points for this answer.

My question may be extended for more of the correlatives. These are some more phrases where adverbs seem fitting to me:

- Ĉio estas mirinde en nia mondo.
- Io ne estas ĝuste pri ĝi.

But in these cases adjectives are clearly correct:

- Io stranga okazis.
- Mi vidas ĉion helan.

Comment: The description as you report it is too imprecise. It does not matter whether there is a noun in the phrase or not, but what the _vere_/_vera_ refers to. _Tio_ itself is not a noun, but it acts as a nominal element (as evidenced by the -o ending), so if you want to refer to it, use the adjective. If you refer to the verb (_estas_), use an adverb, regardless of whether there is a noun around or not.

Comment: I'll reread it and check that I fairly represented it.

Answer (score 11):

The -o correlatives are noun-like and although they don't take a plural, they are described by adjectives, not adverbs. Therefore, in every case that you listed, you would need an adjective.

- Tio estas vera.
- Ĉio estas mirinda en nia mondo.
- Io ne estas ĝusta pri ĝi.

Your last two examples could be adverbs depending on what you mean.

- Io stranga okazis - something strange happened.
- Io strange okazis - something happened strangely.

I'm not sure what this one means.

- Mi vidas ĉion helan.

In any of the cases above, changing the adjective to an adverb means that you're describing the verb, not the -o correlative.

Comment: Clear! Thank you. The last one, yes... I was trying to think of a good example using the accusative. I thought this one meant the same as "Mi vidas cxion kio estas hela"

Comment: In that case, I that sentence sounds good to me "Mi vidas cxion helan" - I see all the bright things.

Answer (score 4):

> put in Tio estas vere, simply because that sounded more familiar. Now I want to know, is that grammatically wrong?

Yes. It is wrong. **Tio** takes the place of a noun. Describing a noun with an adverb doesn't work. Adverbs modify verbs (they also modify adjectives and other adverbs).

**Tio estas vere** = That thing (tio) really is (estas vere)... - It is an incomplete sentence. That thing really is what? Also in this case, it is better form to say **vere estas** rather than **estas vere**.

When you say **Tio estas vera**, it means that thing (tio) equals (estas) true (vera).

There are 70 hits in the tekstaro for **Tio estas vera**. There are a few hits for **Tio estas vere** but only when there is an accompanying adjective.

Comment: Good answer. Though just two small details… Adverbs may modify adjectives or other adverbs, not just verbs. The sentence *Tio estas vere*, although very unusual, is actually grammatical correct, because one can use the existential meaning of *esti* (as in: *Mi pensas, do mi estas.* = I think, therefore I am.; *Estu lumo!* = Let there be light!).

Answer (score 1):

With an -e, the word is an adverb and modifies the verb (or adjective).  So *tio estas vere* is translated as *that truly is*.

An adverb answers the question *how?*.

If you want to modify the subject of the sentence you need to use an adjective.